# How to add Diff Versions of JAR file depending on build variant in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

How to add Diff Versions of JAR file depending on build variant using gradle in android ?

Comment: http://rominirani.com/2014/08/19/gradle-tutorial-part-6-android-studio-gradle/

Answer (score 0):

Use a build variant version of `compile`, like `debugCompile` or `flavor1Compile`.

For example, the following `dependencies` closure references an in-project library module for `debug` builds and an artifact for `release` builds:

```
dependencies {
    debugCompile project(':security')
    releaseCompile 'com.commonsware.cwac:security:0.6.+'
}
```

Since a given build will either be `debug` *or* `release` (not both), only one of those two dependencies will be used for the build.

If you literally mean JARs, you would need to use `...Compile files()` statements that point to the specific JAR. I have not needed to use a bare JAR in Android builds in nearly two years, so I do not have the Gradle syntax for that handy.